# Dispatch action to ngrx/store when using ngModel in Angular

Tags: angular, ngrx-store

I have implemented ng2-search-filter in angular 10 application which works perfectly fine and need to store the search criteria in ngrx/store. In the code below, the search variable is read into the template using ngModel. As per my understanding, action needs to be dispatched and generally is done via a method.How do I dispatch action in this scenario. I have written the dispatch logic below but not sure where to call it.I just hope I am doing it right.

Html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Here" [(ngModel)]="term">
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="btnAddCustomer" (click)="addCustomer()"> Add Customer (Template Driven) </button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <table id="customerdetails-table" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-responsive-md" *ngIf="customerDetails">
          <thead>
            <th>Customer</th>
            <th>Company Name</th>
            <th>Contact Name</th>
            <th>Contact Title</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Region</th>
            <th>Postal Code</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>Fax</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let custDetails of customerDetails.slice((currentPage - 1) * itemsPerPage,currentPage * itemsPerPage ) | filter:term ">
              <td>{{custDetails.customerId}}</td>
              <td>{{custDetails.companyName}}</td>
              <td>{{custDetails.contactName}}</td>
              <td>{{custDetails.contactTitle}}</td>
              <td>{{custDetails.address}}</td>
              <td>{{custDetails.city}}</td>
              <td>{{custDetails.region}}</td>
              <td>{{custDetails.postalCode}}</td>
              <td>{{custDetails.country}}</td>
              <td>{{custDetails.phone}}</td>
              <td>{{custDetails.fax}}</td>
              <td>
                <a [routerLink]="'/customers'" class="table-row-action edit-action"  (click)="editCustomer(custDetails)">
                  edit
                </a>
              </td>
              <td>
                <a [routerLink]="'/customers'" class="table-row-action edit-action"  (click)="deleteCustomer(custDetails.customerId)">
                  delete
                </a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>

     
      <pagination [(ngModel)]="currentPage" (pageChange)="pageChanged($event)" [totalItems]="totalItems" [itemsPerPage]="itemsPerPage" [maxSize]="maxSize"></pagination>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Component

```
export class CustomerComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy  {
  customerDetails: ICustomer[];
  customer: ICustomer;
  public modal: any;
  totalItems: number;
  maxSize = 5;
  currentPage = 1;
  itemsPerPage = 8;
  term: string;
  isEdit: boolean;
  completed$ = new Subject<any>();

  constructor(private customerService: CustomerService,
              public modalService: NgbModal, private store: Store<any>
              ) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getCustomerDetails();
  }

  getCustomerDetails(): void {
    this.customerService.getCustomerDetails()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.customerDetails = data;
        this.totalItems = data.length;
      }
      );
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.completed$.next();                      // <-- close impending subscriptions
    this.completed$.complete();
  }

  pageChanged(currentPageIndex: number): void {
    this.currentPage = currentPageIndex;
 }
}
```

Reducer and Action

```
import { createReducer, createAction, on } from '@ngrx/store';

 export const customerReducer = createReducer(
    {term: '' },
    on(createAction('[Customer] Search Term'), state => {
      console.log('original state: ' + JSON.stringify(state));
      return {
        ...state,
         term: state.term
      };
    })
 );
```

Dispatching the action

```
  this.store.dispatch(
      {type: '[Customer] Search Term'}
    );
```

Screenshot of the devtools

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First you need to define what event you are going to use to fire the action.

Let say you pick `change`, then you could do something like this

*html*

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Here" [(ngModel)]="term" (change)="searchTermChange()">
```

*ts*

```
searchTermChange() {
  this.store.dispatch(customerChangeSearchTerm({ term: this.term }));
}
```

Where `customerChangeTerm` is the action. BTW, is a good practice to separete actions, reducers, selectors, effects into separate files.

One last thing, probably the more usual use case is to handle `input` event. In this case you will wait for x characters and then execute search.

**UPDATE**

Yeah I realize now that there are many things missing or wrong in your state process. First you are not passing the term in the action, second you are not updating the state with the new term.

Ok, so let review the process:

*customers.actions.ts*

```
import { createAction, props } from '@ngrx/store';

export const customerChangeSearchTerm = createAction(
  '[Customer] Change Search Term',
  props<{ term: string }>()
);
```

*customers.reducers.ts*

```
import {
  customersChangeSearchTerm
} from './auth.actions';
import { createReducer, on, Action } from '@ngrx/store';

export const initialState: CustomersState = {
  term: null
};

const reducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(customerChangeSearchTerm, (state, payload) => ({
    ...state,
    term: payload.term
  }))
)
```

BTW, I change `termChange` to `searchTermChange`.

Comment: In ngrx devtools I can see an new action created each time I type something in the input box but dont see the values added to the state. It always showing term is blank string. Updated the post with the screenshot

Comment: @Tom I realize now that there are several things missing in your code, check the update in the answer

Comment: I was getting compilation error on line where dispatch is called. When I wrote the following this.store.dispatch({type: 'customerChangeSearchTerm'}); it compile properly. However when i see devtools . I am seeing always term as null

Comment: If I call it like this  import * as CustomerActions from '../../state/customer.action';  this.store.dispatch(CustomerActions.customerChangeSearchTerm(); I get error An argument for 'props' was not provided

Comment: It works when I do this   this.store.dispatch(CustomerActions.customerChangeSearchTerm({term: this.term}));

Comment: @Tom the purpose of the action is to set the new search term, so you need to pass it the new value, the term is the payload of the action .. You can import just the action you need doing by specifying the action `import { customerChangeSearchTerm } from '../../state/customer.action';` .. Sorry I miss the parameter on the snippet, I have updated the answer